# flexible string replacement in R

Tags: r

I have the string `foo+1234+bar.txt`, and I'm trying to substitute `foo` with `baz` and remove `+bar`:

```
baz+1234.txt
```

I think I should use `gsub`

```
gsub("foo*", "baz", "foo+1234+bar.txt")
```

but I don't know how to selectively keep some of the characters while removing others at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as chained operation. First remove `'+bar'` then replace `'foo'` with `'baz'`.

```
string <- "foo+1234+bar.txt"
sub('foo', 'baz', fixed = TRUE, sub('+bar', '', string, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] "baz+1234.txt"
```